# Getting “-bash: /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min: Permission denied” when trying to make adjustments to Openmediavault

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions, raid

I'm running Openmediavault Linux 4.19.75-v7l+ and I'm running into an issue trying to run the command

```bsh
$ echo 50000 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
```

Or:

```bsh
$ echo 50000 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
```

The console spits this out back at me each time:

> -bash: /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min: Permission denied

I have already created a user under a `/bin/bash` shell and added that user account to pretty much every group.

All I’m trying to do is increase the initial resync speed of a fresh RAID 6 with 5 drives. At the moment, it's saying it’ll take upwards of 30 days (!!!) to finish.

Any thoughts or helpful advice is greatly appretiated!

Comment: Have you tried running it as `sudo` like this: `sudo echo 50000 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min`. Or just even open the file like this — for example with `nano` — and then adding your value? `sudo /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min`

Comment: Neither works. I get the same Permission denied

Comment: Is there even a `/proc/sys/dev/raid/` directory path? It could be that if the directory structure doesn’t even exist then the system won’t allow access to the full `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need root permsision to write that file.

```
sudo echo ...
```

Does not work because sudo does not see the redirection.
use the echo command in a root shell or do it this way instead:

```
echo 50000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
```